# Why does this error occur?: `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement`

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

How can I verify if my code's connection to the Oracle DB is established or not?

Below are the configuration parameters in my spring boot property file:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
oracle.username=username
oracle.password=password
oracle.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//ipaddress:1521/dbname
```

When I am trying to fetch the data from database, it is showing this error :

> `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:` could not prepare statement

Below is the sample code :

```
@Repository
public interface AmountRepository extends JpaRepository<POJO, Integer> {

  @Query(
    value = "select t.mov_flg,t.net_val,t.loc_cd,t.trn_type,t.trn_no,\r\n" + 
      " t.trn_dt,t.created_dt,tr.term_amt,t.gross_val\r\n"
      + " from inv_thdr,\r\n" + 
      " tr where t.trn_no=term_trn.term_no and t.trn_type='EBO' 
  and t.loc_cd=3 and t.trn_no>3", 
    nativeQuery = true
  )
  public List<POJO> getLastHoursData(@Param("transactionNo") Integer transactionNo);
}
```

Comment: Please share your error log or console and can properly format your code

Comment: `Table "tablename" not found`. So you are actually executing a totally different SQL to what you claimed ...